# GPT-3 question answering based on keywords

Tags: nlp, openai-api, gpt-3

I am currently getting accustomed to GPT3, and I am trying to generate questions from a text by also inputting some keywords from that text. Ideally, they would be the answers to that question.

What I tried was to input the text, and simply write `Keywords: dog, cat, mouse` etc., so just enumerating the words, and then input some question examples. But obviously, it is not used to this structure and I was wondering if it was even possible to do it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently working on something similar (but I'm using GPT-J). One thing I find helpful is describing in the input what you want GPT to do.

e.g.: I want to generate a sentence containing all given key-words:

input:

```
Generate a sentence which contains all of the keywords.
Keywords: dog, cat, mouse
Sentence:
```

output:

```
Generate a sentence which contains all of the keywords.
Keywords: dog, cat, mouse
Sentence: I have a dog, a cat and a mouse.
```

Let me know if this helps you, or if you find any other solutions which might help me as well!